# Use of Limit in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, limit, information-schema

[image]

First query is giving fine results but question is about 2nd

When I have given limit 2,2. How two rows can be selected? this is the weied beahaviour query

```
SELECT Ordinal_Position, Column_Name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE
table_schema = 'accounts' AND table_name = 'chequeout' LIMIT 2 , 2
```

What is wrong with 2nd query or its sum bug? What could be the solution?

**Expected result** of second query is  a single row with values `2     and    Amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably a little confused about how to use `LIMIT`:

```
LIMIT <offset>,<limit>
```

`<offset>` means starting row index and `<limit>` tells how much rows.

Comment: Yes this was the thing Actually. My Problem could be solved with ordinal position as well. But the thing I was confused was the limit. Thanks

Comment: Please correct it.

dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html tells

SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15. So Limit 2,1 does not mean I want 2 records. It means I want 1 record beginning from 2nd(2th) poition

Answer (score 2):

Limit 2, 2 means start at record 2 (the third 0,1,2) and display 2 rows

What you seem to want to do is :

```
WHERE Ordinal_Position = 2
```

Comment: Yes your solution seems right. But could not understand 0,1,2 and then two rows why not 3 or only 3rd row? 2,2 why it should not be only 2th means (0,1,2) third row?

Comment: Your solution was right but the thing I was confused in is explained better in EthanB Answer. Thank you as well.